# Builtin method for iadd operation (+=) on integers?

Tags: python, integer

On integers in python we can use:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> a += 2
>>> print(a)
3
```

But if you look in available methods in the integer object you will not find the related method `__iadd__`. E.g. you get an exception if you execute:

```
a.__iadd__(2)  # equal to a += 2
```

So how is the operator `+=` working on integers? And is there a way to reach a builtin method to do the operation so that we can use it in a list comprehension like this:

```
>>> a = 0
>>> summands = [1, 4, 5, 7, 9]
>>> [a.__iadd__(a,i) for i in summands]
>>> print(a)
3
```

The problem is that we can use just method calls and not the `=` operator in this case.

Comment: If there's no `__iadd__` then the interpreter uses `__add__` and a regular assignment. I'm not sure what your goal is with that list comprehension, but it looks funny.

Comment: If you look at `int` class you see it inherits from `object`. `class int(object)` So you might take need to take a look to that class?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that comprehension?! There are certainly "normal" ways to do whatever you want to do there, perhaps `sum` or `reduce`…

Comment: if there is no `__iadd__` method for a type (like `int`), python will use `a = a + i`. as `int`s are immutable, there must be no way to change them in-place.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#in-place-operators

Comment: The hint regarding integers are immutable makes the things clear for me. Thanks.
I don't understand why the question is a duplicate. In the other question my question is not answered (or I do not see it).